# sms text encoding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, character-encoding, sms

All I'm asking is if SMS messages on Windows Phone 7.x are encoded in ASCII or UNICODE format, and in particular, which type.

Practically, I want to convert a string containing greek characters, which the user has typed in a textbox, to a string containing -among other chars- the respective uppercase greek characters, so that the sms will not be limited to have 70 characters only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SmsComposeTask` only allows you to set the message in a string. In .NET, String are *always* encoded in UTF-16, no matter what you do. It will be the `SmsComposeTask` that will convert the string to another encoding when creating the SMS. So unfortunately there's nothing you can do but letting the system pick the encoding for you.

Comment: I see... But in the market, I have found one app that allows you to send an sms message with uppercase greek characters, instead of the lower-case chars that impose the limit of 70 chars/sms. What could be another way to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

SMS encoding is controlled by the cell phone system, and is not a property of the Windows Phone OS.  A hidden prefix to the SMS data specifies whether the following data is in ASCII or Unicode. (The GSM version of the SMS encoding specification is here: [3GPP TS 23.038](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/123000_123099/123038/10.00.00_60/ts_123038v100000p.pdf)).

It is not possible to switch between encodings on a character by character basis, because the cell phone data encoding standards do not support this.